Get list of available voters for a given role in symfony 6
I use voters in Symfony 6 to grant access to operations. Here is an example of one of the voters:
<?php

namespace App\Security\Voter\Admin\Task;

use App\Enum\Role;
use App\Security\Voter\Admin\AdminCachedVoter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;

class TaskVoter extends AdminCachedVoter
{
    public function supportsAttribute(string $attribute): bool
    {
        return in_array(
            $attribute,
            [
                'EA_TASK_INDEX',
                'EA_TASK_NEW',
                'EA_TASK_EDIT',
                'EA_TASK_DELETE'
            ]
        );
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute(string $attribute, mixed $subject, TokenInterface $token): bool
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();
        if (!$user) {
            return false;
        }

        $roles = match ($attribute) {
            'EA_TASK_INDEX', 'EA_TASK_NEW', 'EA_TASK_EDIT' => [
                Role::ROLE_ADMIN,
                Role::ROLE_EDITOR
            ],
            'EA_TASK_DELETE' => [
                Role::ROLE_ADMIN
            ]
        };
        $rolesValues = array_map(static fn(Role $role) => $role->value, $roles);

        return !empty(array_intersect($rolesValues, $user->getRoles()));
    }

}


As I have dozens of such voters created for each entity in symfony it is difficult to know which role has which kind of permission (voter)?
Question: I want to get list of available voters for a given role in Symfony 6?
Update:
If the question is not clear I will try to rephrase a question.
There is isGranted annotation in Symfony which checks if the attributes are granted against the current authentication token and optionally supplied subject.
Question: How to get list of all granted attributes for a given role?

Unless I'm mistaken your are asking two differents questions, do you want to know which voters are supported for a specific role or do you want to get a list of all attributes that would be authorized for your user ?

I need to get list of available attributes for a given role

Sorry, but the question is still unclear (at least to me), including your last comment, I see 3 different questions: for a given role you want to know 1) list of available voters, 2) all granted attributes, 3) list of available attributes. They all mean something different conceptually.

For me list of available voters for a role is the same as all granted attributes for a role. Any help would be valuable, so don't hesitate to answer to any of them. But take into a account the I need to get them (voters|permissions) for a given role, not just all available. Thanks
